# C - pointer in if condition

Tags: c, pointers, comparison, character

Supposing we have the following code sample:

```
char *s="hello";

if(*s=='h'){

    printf("OK");

}
```

The program will display `'OK'`, because the comparison is true.

However, the logic behind this code is a comparison **between a character and an address** (and not the content of the address).

How is it possible to have this condition true, knowing that `*s` is equivalent to an **address** ?

Thanks

Comment: `*s` is *not* an address. You're de-referencing the address at `s`.

Comment: `*s` is a char. `s` (without the `*`) is an address. Get some C book and  read the chapter dealing with pointers.

Comment: Why do you think that "`*s` is equivalent to an address"?  It's not.  What's true is that `s` is equivalent to an address, and `*s` is the object located at that address.  (But it would be a little better to say that `s` is a pointer, and `*s` is the objected pointed to by that pointer.)

Answer (score 1):

It isn't.

`*(s+0)='h' //equal than *s
*(s+1)='e'`

's' is the address of that string.

Comment: Your snippet try to change a string literal, which is undefined behaviour.

Comment: From a mathematical language view the `=` is appropriate to show equality, but seeing as `;` is at the end implying it's C code, you should drop it or explicitly state it isn't C.

Answer (score 0):

`s` is an address, but `*s` is a value which is located by `s` address. Since `s` is `char*`, `*s` is `char`.